# Jenkins JUnit report for maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit

In Jenkins I am not getting the *Publish Junit test result report* option in post build actions for my maven projects.
However, for freestyle projects I am getting the option, and am able to configure it properly.

**Question**: Is there any different approach that I need to follow for Maven projects? How can I configure JUnit for maven projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue:

- [**`JENKINS-9980`**](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9980): Add the "Publish JUnit test result report" option to maven job configuration page

The main idea around this is that a Jenkins Maven job should publish the JUnit report automatically (so no need for this option), while in a freestyle job you may turn it to be a maven job yet having the flexibility of a freestyle/open configuration.

From comments to the JIRA ticket above, you could check suggestion on [this old SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927809/jenkins-not-outputting-junit-report-info-from-file).

Basically, you are left with two options:

- Use a freestyle Jenkins job to have full control, or
- Use a Maven Jenkins job and review your `pom.xml` configuration or the way you are getting JUnit tests executed if the report isn't provided automatically (which could already be the case, hence end of the story).